# Extracting HTML Table data using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to extract all of the brands from [this](https://neighborhoodgoods.com/pages/brands) page using Beautiful Soup. My program so far is:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    opts = Options()
    opts.headless = True
    assert opts.headless  # Operating in headless mode
    browser = Firefox(options=opts)
    browser.get('https://neighborhoodgoods.com/pages/brands')
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    brand = []
    for tag in soup.find('table'):
        brand.append(tag.contents.text)
    print(brand)

    browser.close()
    print('This program is terminated.')
```

I'm struggling with figuring out the right tag to use as the data is nested in tr/td. Any advice? Thanks so much!

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Do you also want the data under the `brandlistRight` class (the description)? or just the company name?

Answer (score 2):

*If I understand your question correctly, you only want to get the company name (the first `<td>` of each table)*

Try using a CSS Selector `td:nth-of-type(1)` which selects the first `<td>` of every table.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://neighborhoodgoods.com/pages/brands"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

print([tag.text for tag in soup.select("td:nth-of-type(1)")])
```

Output:

```
['A.N Other', 'Act + Acre', ...And on.. , 'Wild One']
```